# Sum the value of the cells above going up until blank cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sum the cells above of the current one until an empty cell is found. For instance, in the image below, in the summary row, I want to sum the revenue from the orange cell (the red one) going up until the empty cell. As you can see, some of them are wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Use Ctrl key and up key**

1. Go to the cell where you want the result.
2. Type `= sum(`
3. press up key
4. when cursor moves to the cell above the result cell, keep Ctrl pressed and press up key again - all cells until an empty cell will be selected.
5. Hit enter.