# Sum upwards until another column's value is met

Tags: google-sheets

I found a handful solutions for summing down, but nothing for summing up.

Example table:

```
type | value
A    | -
B    | 5
C    | 10
D    | 7
A    | [SUM1 = 7+10+5 = 22]
B    | 4
B    | 2
C    | 3
C    | 5
A    | [SUM2 = 5+3+2+4 = 14]
```

Goal: Each SUM cell (type A) is summing upwards until the next A is seen in the "type" column.

You can open and edit this example as [Google Sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HG7NyVIxM0knd1MLxSO0oPRIE0x3__-wabQvNUcyhj0/edit?usp=sharing).

I have tried MATCH, VLOOKUP, INDEX and others without success.

`=MATCH("A";A2:A11;0)` would give me always the position of the first "A" from top.

`=INDEX(B2:B11;MATCH("A";A2:A11;0);0)` would give me the value, not the cell index.

A similiar question [Sum the value of the cells above going up until blank cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121908/sum-the-value-of-the-cells-above-going-up-until-blank-cell) only shows how to do this by hand.

Another similar question does not answer the case above: [Getting a sum of cells (bottom to top) in Google Sheets until a specific value is matched](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95588/51145)

This [post on Google Groups](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/tzTgrDim_lY/BheM2HaAo2kJ) proposes something I don't grasp:

`=if(trim(A9)="TOTALS:",sum(arrayformula(index(B8):index(B:B,min(arrayformula(if(isnumber(B1:B8),row(B1:B8))))))),iferror(1/0))`

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following formula into all type "A" columns:

```
=subtotal(9,indirect("b"&ArrayFormula((match(2,1/(indirect("A1:A"&row()-1)="A"))))&":b"&row()-1))
```

You might need to change the b & a's on the formula if your data is on another column. The solution is also on your Google Sheets.